# In the integral of a function, why is it that I am able to take out a function and claim it is smaller than the integral itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Could you please explain what happens in the second last line, where they had the integral larger or equal to the e^-s integral of 1/t. I am confused as it seems that they just pulled the e^-s out and claimed that it was smaller than the integral itself. What law are they using here? sorry I did not type in Latex, but please refer to the image below. thank you.

[image: integral of a fucction]

Comment: You are told why: "On $[0,1]$, $\mathrm{e}^{-st} \geq \mathrm{e}^{-s}$ for all $s$."  Why is that explanation unsatisfactory?

Comment: @EricTowers  OP does not understand how that is being used.

Comment: yes but  e− has no integral here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is a general fact that, if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then
$$  \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \geq \int_a^b g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
(To prove this, observe that $f(x) - g(x) \geq 0$.  Then subtract the right-hand side of the display form the left-hand side, observe that the new (single) integral on the left is an integral of an everywhere nonnegative function, so is nonnegative.)

Then, from $\mathrm{e}^{-st} \geq \mathrm{e}^{-s}$ on the interval of integration, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{-st} &\geq \mathrm{e}^{-s}, \\
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-st}}{t} &\geq \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-s}}{t} \qquad t \neq 0, \\
\int_0^1 \; \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-st}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t
    &\geq \int_0^1 \; \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-s}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{-s}\int_0^1 \; \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{,}
\end{align*}
because $\mathrm{e}^{-s}$ is independent of $t$ so is constant while evaluating the integral.

Comment: when you say subtract the right-hand side of the display, which display do you mean?

Comment: the new single integral is f-g? thanks

Comment: @JosephRock : There is only one display prior to that sentence.

Comment: @JosephRock : Yes, the left-hand side is $$  \int_a^b \;f(x) - g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$

Comment: i see, from here do you use the linear transformation property of integrals? apologies for the rudimentary question if it is

Comment: @JosephRock : No.  You use the inequality with which we started that paragraph.  This integrand is everywhere nonnegative, so the integral is nonnegative.  So the claimed inequality holds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113215/discussion-between-joseph-rock-and-eric-towers).

Comment: OP doesn’t realize it’s a constant in the integral.

Comment: u are right randall